# Polymer - Paper+Iron input not working

Tags: javascript, authentication, polymer

I'm trying to create a login page based on [this](https://auth0.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-polymer-and-web-components/) tutorial. I tried the original code, and the following, too:

```
        <paper-input-container>
            <label>Username</label>
            <iron-input id="username" type="text" bind-value="{{formData.username}}"></iron-input>
        </paper-input-container>

        <paper-input-container>
            <label>Password</label>
            <iron-input id="password" type="password" bind-value="{{formData.password}}"></iron-input>
        </paper-input-container>
```

However, in either cases, my input field is non-modifiable. I cannot click inside to start providing data, nor are the initial labels showing (the cursor also doesn't change from mouse to type icon):

[image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: The above code looks fine it might be good to see the whole element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the elements that you want to use? You need to import them so Polymer can translate them into HTML tags that the browsers can understand.

From the tutorial:

> Now we'll import these new dependencies along with iron-ajax, paper-button, and iron-localstorage. We don't need to install iron-localstorage with Bower because it came packaged with the starter kit.
>
> Note: You can check your /bower_components directory to see what other Polymer components are automatically installed.
>
> The HTML imports for register-login should now look like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-localstorage/iron-localstorage.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
```

Also, you seem to be missing *is="iron-input"* in:

```
<input is="iron-input" id="username" type="text" bind-value="{{formData.username}}">
```